# Luhn algorithm not working for 13 digit Visa card

Tags: c#, algorithm, luhn

I am working on a Visa credit card generator and I'm not seeing the problem with the following:
My code seems to work for 16 digit card numbers, however, it doesn't seem to work for 13 digit cards, as the generated card numbers are invalid on both online testers and on my app.

Code:

```
var randomNum = new Random();
int [] lengths = new int[] { 13, 16 };
int length = lengths[randomNum.Next(lengths.Length)];
int [] str;
int [] reversed;
var lastDigit = 0;
var sum = 0;

if (length == 16)
{
    str = new int[16];
    reversed = new int[15];
}
else
{
    str = new int[13];
    reversed = new int[12];
}

Random rnd = new Random();
while (pos < length - 1)
{
    str[pos++] = rnd.Next(0, 9);
}

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
{
    reversed[i] = str[str.Length - i - 2];
}

for (pos = 0; pos < length - 1; pos++)
{
    if (pos % 2 == 0 && length == 16)
    {
        reversed[pos] *= 2;
        if (reversed[pos] > 9)
            reversed[pos] = reversed[pos] - 9;
    }
    else if (pos % 2 == 1 && length == 13)
    {
        reversed[pos] *= 2;
        if (reversed[pos] > 9)
            reversed[pos] = reversed[pos] - 9;
    }

    sum += reversed[pos];
}

lastDigit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
str[length - 1] = lastDigit;
```

I apologize for copying the whole code, but I thought it would make things more understandable.

The algorithm I followed from http://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html:

- Drop the last digit from the number. The last digit is what we want to check against
- Reverse the numbers
- Multiply the digits in odd positions (1, 3, 5,    etc.) by 2 and
  subtract 9 to all any result higher than 9
- Add all the
  numbers together
- The check digit (the last number of the card) is the amount that you
  would need to add to get a multiple of 10 (Modulo 10)

Sample card numbers generated by my code:

- 16 digit: 4145422641287432 - Valid
- 13 digit: 4354735186403 - Invalid
  (The sum before adding the check
  digit was 47 meaning 3 would be the check digit resulting in the whole sum being 50 => 50%10=0)

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any valid 13-digit credit card numbers???

Comment: @barakmanos following the link seems that Visa cards number are between 13 and 16 digits

Comment: Couple of points: why are you using `pos % 2 == 1` for `length=13`, should not it be the same as `length=16`? Also, last digit could simply be be just `10-(sum % 10)`?

Comment: I don't see the point of reversing the string just to add the values together. Also, shouldn't the same algorithm be able to handle numbers of arbitrary lengths?

Comment: Old visa cards have 13 digits.
@SandipanDeyActually, using because in the reversed array, I am dropping the last digit. If I drop the last digit of the 16 digit, I have 15 left, resulting in (reading from left to right) indexes with 0, 2, 4 etc. If I however drop the digit from the 13 digit number, I have 12 digits and the ones that should be doubled are on idexes 1, 3, 5 etc.
The last digit couldn't be what you said because if a number is already divisible by 10, the new digit added would be 10 e.g. 10 - (50%10) = 10,  not 0.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for the note, but I've also tried without reversing, the algorithm would be almost the same but it just doesn't work for 13 digits. Atleast that's what the online validators would say.